# Creating an angular-meteor project in WebStorm 11

Tags: node.js, meteor, webstorm, meteor-blaze, angular-meteor

I use WebStorm 11 which supports angular-meteor. However, when I create a new Meteor project, it uses Blaze. How can I change it to use Angular instead of Blaze?

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the settings: 'File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Templates' -> 'Open html files as Handlebars'